# Filtering by email addresses and names in SurveyMonkey's API v3

Tags: surveymonkey

I'm upgrading my application from SurveyMonkey's API v2 to v3 and using the [liogi/surveymonkey-api-v3](https://github.com/liogi/surveymonkey-api-v3) library to wrap around my API calls and have run into a problem.

The `email`, `first_name`, and `last_name` parameters for such endpoints as [`GET /surveys/{id}/responses/bulk`](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-responses-bulk) seem to be ignored. No matter what value I enter for them, no responses get filtered out of my results.

**Is this a bug?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes adding those as GET parameters in your request should filter responses by that recipient information.

For example:

```
/v3/surveys/<survey_id>/responses/bulk?email=test@example.com
```

Will return responses for survey `<survey_id>` where the recipient had email `test@example.com`. Note that only collectors of type [email invitation](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Email-Invitation-Collector) have contact information that you can filter by. So responses taken by weblink will never have that data.

I just tested it out on the bulk endpoint and it successfully filtered it to just the one response with the email I used. I would first try to track the request your library is making to make sure it is sending the proper request format, if the request is proper and it still isn't filtering I would contact SurveyMonkey with more details about your request as in that case it'd likely be a bug.

Comment: I'm accessing a weblink-type collector. It looks like the SurveyMonkey API v3 docs has a small error, in that some other endpoints like `GET /surveys/{id}/rollups` mention that for the `email`, `first_name`, and `last_name` parameters, "Responses must come from an email collector", but that note isn't included in the docs for `GET /surveys/{id}/responses/bulk`.